# How to add value to a php variable everytime the html is clicked?

Tags: php

im trying to add 15 to `$offset` everytime `<a href='index.php?hello=true'>Next page</a>` is clicked.  please help...

```
<a href='index.php?hello=true'>Next page</a>
```

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "search";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

$offset = 0;
$rowcount = 15;

$sql = "SELECT title, vidpage, thumbnail
        FROM moviesearch
        LIMIT $offset, $rowcount";

$result = $conn -> query($sql);

if (isset($_GET['hello'])) {

    $offset += 15;

        $sql = "SELECT title, vidpage, thumbnail
        FROM moviesearch
        LIMIT $offset, $rowcount";

        $result = $conn -> query($sql);

    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<table id='main-table'>";
        echo "
        <tr>
        <li class='vid-thumbnail'>
            <a href=".$row['vidpage']."><img src=".$row['thumbnail']." width='195' height='290' style='box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);'></img></a>
            <div class='vid-text'><a class='vid-title-text' href='vid-page/searching.php'>".$row['title']."</a></div>
        </li>
        </tr>
        ";
        echo "</table>";
    }
  }

else if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<table id='main-table'>";
        echo "
        <tr>
        <li class='vid-thumbnail'>
            <a href=".$row['vidpage']."><img src=".$row['thumbnail']." width='195' height='290' style='box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);'></img></a>
            <div class='vid-text'><a class='vid-title-text' href='vid-page/searching.php'>".$row['title']."</a></div>
        </li>
        </tr>
        ";
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome. What doesn't work? What errors do you get? Do you store `$offset` somewhere so it isn't "reset" everytime you call the page?

Comment: its not exactly an error, its just that whenever i click the 'next page' the $offset wont add by 15 again...

Comment: Either store `$offset` in a session or use a more descriptive URL parameter like `?page=1`, `?page=2` etc. or `?offset=15`, `?offset=30` instead of `hello`

Comment: sorry, it took me so long to respond back and yes i actually found an answer to my question from a teacher. I dont know how to explain the answer (since i dont understand a lot of the terms yet) but it is related to your answer so Thank You!

Comment: No problem, glad it works ;)